# Change of subsite address and now points to an error

Tags: development, administration, url, sub-site

I've managed to change the subsites address to 'Home.aspx' by mistake and need to change it back to something, what's the best way to do this? doesnt let me access the subsite anymore

Answer (score 0):

Open the site in designer and then open any site page. Then set it as the home page.

Alternatively you can directly open the Site Settings page using URL

```
http://site/subsite/_layouts/settings.aspx
```

Comment: I don't think it recognises the subsite as it has a .aspx Wont open any pages in designer when clicked but all there as options

Answer (score 0):

change the folder that it looks onto in SPDesigner on the subsite's details/home screen